# java htmlcleaner crashes while cleaning

Tags: java, xhtml, html-parsing, htmlcleaner

Hi in my code i run the following lines, but this code crashes during execution.

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);

final HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();

DomSerializer doms = new DomSerializer(props, true);

org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDoc = null;

try {
    TagNode node = cleaner.clean(input);
    xmlDoc = doms.createDOM(node);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Tiding error ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error's stacktrace:

```
NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.checkDOMNSErr(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2535)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrNSImpl.setName(AttrNSImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrNSImpl.<init>(AttrNSImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createAttributeNS(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setAttributeNS(ElementImpl.java:656)
    at org.htmlcleaner.DomSerializer.setAttributes(DomSerializer.java:97)
    at org.htmlcleaner.DomSerializer.createDOM(DomSerializer.java:37)
```

Can anyone help to find out why it's happening?

Sincerely, Zoli

Answer (score 0):

HTMLCleaner has encountered a problem dealing with namespaces. Here is an example of an XML Namespace declaration that will give it trouble:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" 
  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
```

as you can see the itemscope attribute is broken so HtmlCleaner throws the NAME_SPACE_ERR.

One way to avoid the problem is to add the line

```
props.setNamespacesAware(false);
```

which turns namespace handling off.